# Reference R data frame column name as a string, given only the column name

Tags: r, rlang

I have a data frame df. It has a column named `b`. I know this column name, although I do not know its position in the data frame. I know that colnames(df) will give me a vector of character strings that are the names of all the columns, but I do not know how to get a string for this particular column. In other words, I want to obtain the string "b". How can I do that? I imagine this may involve the rlang package, which I have difficulty understanding.

Here's an example:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(1:8)
b <- c(23,34,45,43,32,45,68,78)
c <- c(0.34,0.56,0.97,0.33,-0.23,-0.36,-0.11,0.17)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

tf <- function(df,MYcol) {
  print(paste0("The name of the input column is ",MYcol)) # does not work
  print(paste0("The name of the input column is ",{{MYcol}})) # does not work
  y <- {{MYcol}} # This gives the values in column b as it shoulkd
}
z <- tf(df,b) # Gives undesired values - I want the string "b"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question... Of course if you have a specific index in mind can check it with `colnames(df)[index]`.

Or you could do `index=which('A and B'==colnames(df))` to find the index of the column is that what you're asking?

Comment: My problem arises within a function I am writing. Two of its inputs are the data frame name (df) and the column name of interest (SomeName). Within my function I want to manipulate the values in SomeName and I also want to print a title that makes use of SomeName as a character string. Does that help?

Comment: Do you mean a string name of the data frame? Not the actual data frame itself?

Comment: I mean a string name of one of the columns of the data frame. Say my data frame is df and it has three columns named a, b and c. The inputs to my function are df and b. Outside the function I know the second column is the input, but inside the column I do not. I want to convert the column name b, which is the input to the function, to "b" within the function.

Comment: I added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot pass column name as string in the function (`tf(df,"b")`) directly, you can use `deparse` + `substitute`.

```
tf <- function(df,MYcol) {
  col <- deparse(substitute(MYcol))
  print(paste0("The name of the input column is ",col)) 
  return(col)
}

z <- tf(df,b) 
#[1] "The name of the input column is b"
z
#[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as_string` with `enquo/ensym`

```
tf <- function(df, MYcol) {
 
 mycol <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(MYcol))
  print(glue::glue("The name of the input column is {mycol}")) 
  return(mycol)
}

z <- tf(df,b) 
The name of the input column is b
z
#[1] "b"
```